# In a java Jframe can I add/remove a Jlabel from view using a checkbox?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcheckbox

Im making an application that lets me perform hashes, at the top I want to have a group of check boxes basically saying the four different hash types I have. When the check boxes are selected I want the labels to appear showing the hashed entered text.

I've attached an image to hopefully make it easier to understand what I mean. The reason I'm doing this is so that when the final program is made with almost 10 rows of text boxes and labels it can be reduced only to show the ones that the user wishes to see.[This hopefully should explain what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsHjp.png)

I've been able to get it so the checkboxes make it visible or not visible but that also then just leaves a blank space where one row of labels used to be rather than moving everything up a row

I've now added my coding so people can see how I'm doing it currently and help define where needs to be modified

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hasher extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String UserInput;
    private JTextField textInputField;
    private static JLabel MD5Hashed,MD5Label;
    private static JCheckBox MD5Check, SHA1Check, SHA256Check, FileCheck;
    private JFrame contentPane;

public Hasher() {
    this.setTitle("Hasher");
    Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1) );
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(88,148,202));

    //CheckBoxes
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        MD5Check = new JCheckBox("MD5");
        MD5Check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    boolean Visible = MD5Check.isSelected();
    MD5Hashed.setVisible(Visible);
    MD5Label.setVisible(Visible);
            }
        });
        checkBoxPanel.add(MD5Check);
        SHA1Check = new JCheckBox("SHA-1");
        checkBoxPanel.add(SHA1Check);
        SHA256Check = new JCheckBox("SHA-256");
        checkBoxPanel.add(SHA256Check);
        FileCheck = new JCheckBox("File Hashing");
        checkBoxPanel.add(FileCheck);
        mainPanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
        contentPane.add(mainPanel);


//Entered data to perform hash on
    contentPane.add(new JLabel ("   Enter text to hash"));
    textInputField = new JTextField();
    //HashingProcess inputListener = new HashingProcess( );
    //textInputField.addActionListener(inputListener);
    contentPane.add( textInputField);

//MD5 hash is completed 
    MD5Label = new JLabel( "   Using MD5 the hash is: " );
    contentPane.add( MD5Label);
    MD5Hashed = new JLabel( "??") ;
    contentPane.add( MD5Hashed );
    MD5Hashed.setVisible(false);
    MD5Label.setVisible(false);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hasher theWindow = new Hasher( );
    theWindow.setSize(400, 400 );
    theWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    theWindow.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: *"In a java Jframe can I add/remove a Jlabel from view.."* Sure. Set the icon to null and the text to `""` (an empty string). Voila! It is invisible..

Answer (score 3):

You have two frames...

```
public class Hasher extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //...
    private JFrame contentPane;
    //..
```

This immediately raises the question, which one is actually on the screen and which one are you actually interacting with? While this might not be directly related to your problem, it is confusing.

As a general rule of thumb, don't extend from top level containers like `JFrame`, it locks you into a single use case and can cause no end of confusion.  Instead, start with a `JPanel` and add it to an instance of `JFrame` or any other container you like.

The "main probable" problem is, Swing is lazy.  It won't update the UI until you tell it or the UI is resized.

When adding and removing components, you need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container to trigger an update - this is what's actually going wrong in your code, you're referencing `contentPane`, by that is `private JFrame contentPane;` and not the `contentPane` of the `JFrame` from which `Hasher` extends ... see, confusion.

Happening dug around your code a bit, it's obvious that you have a lot of repeated operations going on, the only core difference is the algorithm used to hash the text.

So, with that in mind, we can create some basic classes to do most of the work, for example...

```
public class HashPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel hashedLabel;
    private JLabel promptLabel;

    private HashAlgorithim algorithim;

    public HashPane(String labelText, HashAlgorithim algorithim) {
        setOpaque(false);
        this.algorithim = algorithim;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        promptLabel = new JLabel(labelText);
        add(promptLabel);
        hashedLabel = new JLabel("??");
        add(hashedLabel);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        hashedLabel.setText(algorithim.generateHash(text));
    }

}
```

This is just two labels, which show a prompt and a result.  The result is generated via a plug algorithm which is used to generate the hash for the supplied text

The algorithm itself is just a `interface` which defines the basic contract...

```
public interface HashAlgorithm {
    public String generateHash(String from);
}
```

You would then need to create an implementation of each algorithm you wanted to use

Now, making a panel visible/invisible simply becomes a matter of associating a `JCheckBox` with a `HashPane` which can be achieved through a simple `Map`...

```
public class Hasher extends JPanel {
    //...
    private Map<JCheckBox, HashPane> mapPanes;

    public Hasher() {
        //...
        HashPane md5Pane = new HashPane("MD5 hash = ", new NotAMD5Alorithim());
        //...
        HashPane sha1Pane = new HashPane("SHA-1 hash = ", new NotAMSHA1Alorithim());
        //..
        mapPanes = new HashMap<>(25);
        mapPanes.put(MD5Check, md5Pane);
        mapPanes.put(SHA1Check, sha1Pane);
        //...
```

You can then use a single `ActionListener` to manage all the `JCheckBox`s

```
public class Hasher extends JPanel {
    //...
    private Map<JCheckBox, HashPane> mapPanes;

    public Hasher() {
        //...
        ActionHandler listener = new ActionHandler();
        for (Entry<JCheckBox, HashPane> entry : mapPanes.entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey().addActionListener(listener);
            entry.getValue().setVisible(false);
        }

    }

    protected class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
            HashPane hashPane = mapPanes.get(cb);
            hashPane.setVisible(cb.isSelected());
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

    }
```

And because I pretty much butchered your code...

[image: Hide and Show]

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

    public class Hasher extends JPanel {

        String UserInput;
        private JTextField textInputField;
        private static JCheckBox MD5Check, SHA1Check, SHA256Check, FileCheck;

        private Map<JCheckBox, HashPane> mapPanes;

        public Hasher() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBackground(new Color(88, 148, 202));

            //CheckBoxes
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
            MD5Check = new JCheckBox("MD5");
            checkBoxPanel.add(MD5Check);
            SHA1Check = new JCheckBox("SHA-1");
            checkBoxPanel.add(SHA1Check);
            SHA256Check = new JCheckBox("SHA-256");
            checkBoxPanel.add(SHA256Check);
            FileCheck = new JCheckBox("File Hashing");
            checkBoxPanel.add(FileCheck);
            mainPanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
            add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel centerPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            centerPane.setOpaque(false);
            JPanel inputPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            inputPane.setOpaque(false);

    //Entered data to perform hash on
            inputPane.add(new JLabel("Enter text to hash: "));
            textInputField = new JTextField(20);
            inputPane.add(textInputField);

            centerPane.add(inputPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel output = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            output.setOpaque(false);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            HashPane md5Pane = new HashPane("MD5 hash = ", new NotAMD5Alorithim());
            output.add(md5Pane, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            HashPane sha1Pane = new HashPane("SHA-1 hash = ", new NotAMSHA1Alorithim());
            output.add(sha1Pane, gbc);

            // last pane
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            output.add(new JLabel(), gbc);

            centerPane.add(output);

            add(centerPane);

            mapPanes = new HashMap<>(25);
            mapPanes.put(MD5Check, md5Pane);
            mapPanes.put(SHA1Check, sha1Pane);
            //...

            ActionHandler listener = new ActionHandler();
            for (Entry<JCheckBox, HashPane> entry : mapPanes.entrySet()) {
                entry.getKey().addActionListener(listener);
                entry.getValue().setVisible(false);
            }

        }

        protected class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                HashPane hashPane = mapPanes.get(cb);
                hashPane.setVisible(cb.isSelected());
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new Hasher());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public interface HashAlgorithm {
            public String generateHash(String from);
        }

        public class NotAMD5Alorithim implements HashAlgorithm {

            @Override
            public String generateHash(String from) {
                return "bananas";
            }

        }

        public class NotAMSHA1Alorithim implements HashAlgorithm {

            @Override
            public String generateHash(String from) {
                return "bananas";
            }

        }

        public class HashPane extends JPanel {

            private JLabel hashedLabel;
            private JLabel promptLabel;

            private HashAlgorithm algorithim;

            public HashPane(String labelText, HashAlgorithm algorithim) {
                setOpaque(false);
                this.algorithim = algorithim;
                setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                promptLabel = new JLabel(labelText);
                add(promptLabel);
                hashedLabel = new JLabel("??");
                add(hashedLabel);
            }

            public void setText(String text) {
                hashedLabel.setText(algorithim.generateHash(text));
            }

        }

    }
```

Having said all that, I might be tempted to have the `JCheckBox` in the `HashPane` and has the `HashPane` always visible and simply disable the output text ... or simply not bother and always have all the algorithms available all the time

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   boolean Visible = MD5Check.isSelected();
   MD5Hashed.setVisible(Visible);
   MD5Label.setVisible(Visible);
}
```

to:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    boolean Visible = MD5Check.isSelected();
    MD5Hashed.setVisible(Visible);
    MD5Label.setVisible(Visible);
    contentPane.validate();
    contentPane.repaint();
 }
```

If You want to remove MD5Hashed and MD5Label then  something like this:

```
{
if(MD5Check.isSelected()){
    MD5Hashed.remove();
    MD5Label.remove();
}
else{
    contentPane.add( MD5Label);
    contentPane.add( MD5Hashed );
}

    contentPane.validate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that with the .remove method, however when I do that I can't then re-add it so its visible again?

Comment: How are adding it back? You could check if your JLabel is visible if it is not then add it, if it is then remove it. Remember that after any change that will change the GUI you must run validate() and repaint(), so that GUI will "refresh"

Comment: I've now added my coding so you can see how I was doing it before and maybe clarify where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle `Events` for all `check-box while check/uncheck,`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       if(all check-box un-checked){
            // someLable.setVisible(false);
       }else if(MD5 checked){
           // peform operation based upon MD5
           // someLable.setVisible(true);
       }
       // likewise for all others
      }
```