# Trying to get a jlabel to be completely removed/added to jframe through use of checkboxes

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use checkboxes so that 2 labels (or other objects) have the option to be completely removed or added through the use of a textbox at the top of the window in a jframe. I can manage to do it so they're not visible but want it so that they're removed and all of the other stuff moves up into place so to speak. This is my code so far...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hasher extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String UserInput;
    private JTextField textInputField;
    private static JLabel MD5Hashed,MD5Label;
    private static JCheckBox MD5Check, SHA1Check, SHA256Check, FileCheck;
    private JFrame contentPane;

    public Hasher() {
        this.setTitle("Hasher");
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1) );
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(88,148,202));

        //CheckBoxes
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
            MD5Check = new JCheckBox("MD5");
            MD5Check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean Visible = MD5Check.isSelected();
        if (Visible == true);{
            contentPane.add(MD5Label);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
        }
        if (Visible == false);{
            contentPane.remove(MD5Label);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
        }
                }
            });
            checkBoxPanel.add(MD5Check);
            SHA1Check = new JCheckBox("SHA-1");
            checkBoxPanel.add(SHA1Check);
            SHA256Check = new JCheckBox("SHA-256");
            checkBoxPanel.add(SHA256Check);
            FileCheck = new JCheckBox("File Hashing");
            checkBoxPanel.add(FileCheck);
            mainPanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
            contentPane.add(mainPanel);


    //Row One : Entered data to perform hash on
        contentPane.add(new JLabel ("   Enter text to hash"));
        textInputField = new JTextField();
        //HashingProcess inputListener = new HashingProcess( );
        //textInputField.addActionListener(inputListener);
        contentPane.add( textInputField);

    //Row Three: MD5 hash is completed  
        MD5Label = new JLabel( "   Using MD5 the hash is: " );
        //contentPane.add( MD5Label);
        MD5Hashed = new JLabel( "??") ;
        contentPane.add( MD5Hashed );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hasher theWindow = new Hasher( );
        theWindow.setSize(400, 400 );
        theWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        theWindow.setVisible(true);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You problem is, your `if` statements are been ignored because they have a trailing `;`

```
if (Visible == true); // <-- This be bad
{
    contentPane.add(MD5Label);
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
if (Visible == false);
{
    contentPane.remove(MD5Label);
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

So, basically each time it's called, it both adds and removes the component

Instead you should be doing something more like...

```
if (Visible)
{
    contentPane.add(MD5Label);
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
} 
else 
{
    contentPane.remove(MD5Label);
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

In fact, it should just be...

```
MD5Label.setVisible(Visible);
contentPane.revalidate();
contentPane.repaint();
```

That would have the same effect as adding/removing the components

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

And before any one asks, I still recommend the structural changes I suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215775/in-a-java-jframe-can-i-add-remove-a-jlabel-from-view-using-a-checkbox)

Comment: enough is use `setVisible(Visible)` method.

Comment: @Victor1125 Agreeded, I should have added that in

Comment: I managed to get it working, (yay me) but now the only problem is I have a lot of stuff going on in my program, is there any way I could set an order per say for when they're re-added? so that they come back into a specific order when removed/added...this is just little bits of detail to make it look better

Comment: @TheJordyluke Yes, use setVisible